# Rename column name in mssql using knex

Tags: node.js, sql-server, knex.js

How can I rename a column name using knex and mssql in nodejs? I tried this but I get a syntax error `RequestError: Incorrect syntax near '.'`. I used Postman for this request.

```
router.get('/users', function (req, res, next) {
    knex.raw('sp_rename users.id, id_user, column')
        .then(() => {
            res.json({
                success: true,
                message: "Success."
            })
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
            res.json({
                success: false,
                message: "Error."
            })
        })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters for sp_rename are strings which need to be in quotes
You need to escape the contained single quotes, such as this (SQL escaping)

```
'sp_rename ''users.id'', ''id_user'', ''column'''
```

I can't find how to escape singles quote in knex

Comment: With ' ' it's not working, but I tried with " " so `'sp_rename "users.id", "id_user", "column"'` and it worked. I forgot they must be inside quotes. Thank you!

Comment: I'm sorry, but what can I do if the actual column name is something like this `id user` and I want to change it into `id_user`. How can I write `users.id user`? What kind of escape do I need?

Comment: I found out the answer, I just need something like `users.[id user]`